# How to check what control is inside a table cell

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, controls

I'm trying to check what control I have inside a table cell and if that control is a checkbox, check it.

What I have so far looks like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_fileTablePersonal').rows[1].cells;

if (x[3].typeof == "Checkbox") {
    var chk = x[3];
    chk.checked = true;
} else {
    alert("Isn't Checkbox");
}
```

Since my checkboxes created dynamically; I can't just get the ID of the checkbox, I will be looping through the column to search for each checkbox; I just need to be able to check if that checkbox is a checkbox and then check it.

Comment: using jquery is what I think you should do.

Comment: Well how can I go about doing it in JQuery then? I already have the JQuery files linked to my project

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you didn't specify jQuery, I made up a pure JavaScript sollution:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_fileTablePersonal tr:nth-child(1) input[type=checkbox]");

for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use jquery. it will be simpler

```
$('your_cell').find(':checkbox').length
```